# On screen keyboard: why does it have no special keys like Esc, Ctrl, Alt, Tab or arrow keys?

Tags: keyboard, special-characters, onscreen-keyboard

There's one issue that is bothering me with Ubuntu on my tablet: why does the default on-screen keyboard not have any special function keys like Esc, Ctrl, Alt, Tab or arrow keys? That makes using e.g. terminal in tablet mode pretty much impossible.

In another question about that topic from 2019 I found an answer saying the default keyboard is generated from Unicode, which does not contain these special characters. That's fine, but if you want to actually use that keyboard actively with Linux these non-Unicode special keys are absolutely essential. I'm a bit puzzled by this.

Part one of my Question: is there any way to enable at least arrow keys, tab and ctrl in the default on screen keyboard?

Part two: in similar questions it was recommended to install onboard or florence as an alternative. If it's not possible to extend the default keyboard with special keys, how do I switch the default keyboard that comes up when I try to input text in a text field to another keyboard? I have onboard installed, but the default keyboard still comes up and besides launching onboard manually I couldn't find a way to make accessibility mode default to onboard.

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: Ubuntu 21.04, using default on-screen keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow forgot. It's Ubuntu 21.04 using the default on-screen keyboard. As I said in the second part of my question, other on-screen keyboards exist, but I couldn't find a way to make another keyboard the default keyboard.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing after Ubuntu in all its wisdom proceeded to disable Bluetooth entirely, and then to prompt me to use my (Bluetooth) keyboard to answer questions during a system upgrade. Even with the on screen keyboard I was left dead in the water. Brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution via [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/tsfagf/how_are_the_on_screen_keyboard_on_surface_linux/) Reddit thread. There's a Gnome extension adding the missing keys [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4413/improved-osk/).

Comment: Hello. As your answer is only links it is not really an answer. What about later when the links do not work? If the links have info needed for the answer include that info in the body of the answer.

Comment: There is nothing more I can add other than attaching the linked Gnome extension directly to this post. The link goes to extensions.gnome.org, which is the official Gnome extension repository as far as I know. There is no setting or anything, just install the extension and you're good.

Comment: Then say that in the answer and in English

Comment: Again, there is nothing more I can add than the link to the extension. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220121233831/https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4413/improved-osk/) is a link to archive.org in case the official Gnome extension repository ceases to exist.

Comment: This "accessibility feature" that requires third party extensions to become unbroken is absolutely hilarious. Canonical never fails to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Onboard press the  <kbd>?123</kbd>  button to enter numbers and symbols.